# Async Await Persistant Warning

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am getting the warning "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.  Although it sounds obvious, I thought I was covered because I run all the processes and have an Await Task.WhenAll() in my processFiles method.  Do I need to be doing this a different way?  Any thoughts would be kindly appreciated.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;


    namespace ProcessFiles
    {
        public partial class ProcessFiles : Form 
        {
            public ProcessFiles(int userLevel, int userID)
            {
            }

            private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                processFiles();

            }

            async Task<int> processFiles()
            {
                var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (string fileName in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    processingTasks.Add(process012(fileName));
                    processingTasks.Add(process123(fileName));
                    processingTasks.Add(process234(fileName));

                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
                return (1);
            }


            async Task<int> process173(string fileName)
            {
                return (retVal);

            }

            async Task<int> process032(string fileName)
            {
                return (retVal);
            }

            async Task<int> process018(string fileName)
            {
                return (retVal);
            }
```

Comment: You have 3 methods with the `async` keyword but no await. Isn't the message clear? Also, if you want to return a completed task use `return Task.FromResult` without `async`

Comment: I thought  await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks); was sufficient to wait for everything to complete.  The last three methods don't have an await in them.

Comment: they have an `async` which means they need an `await`. And so does `btnProcess_Click`

Comment: Okay - thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use async Task in your processXXX methods just return Task<int> instead. You will await the tasks in main processFiles() method:

```
        private async void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await processFiles();
        }

        async Task<int> processFiles()
        {
            var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (string fileName in listBox1.Items)
            {
                processingTasks.Add(process012(fileName));
                processingTasks.Add(process123(fileName));
                processingTasks.Add(process234(fileName));

            }
            await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
            return (1);
        }


        Task<int> process173(string fileName)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(retVal)
        }

        Task<int> process032(string fileName)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(retVal)
        }

        Task<int> process018(string fileName)
        {
           return Task.FromResult(retVal)
        }
```

Comment: There are 3 more methods without `await`

Comment: Theres' NO reason to await a completed task. Just use `Task<int> process032(..){return Task.FromResult(retVal);}` if you want. Using `async/await` here generates a state machine that is never used

Comment: Must there be an await inside each method?  My plan is for all the methods to run at the same time and await them at the end with  Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);   Is that not enough?

Comment: Thank you so much!  Runs much faster now :)